# My mouse gets unresponsive when my system runs CPU intensive jobs. How can I find out if it's the mouse or some other component's fault?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, asus-laptop

I have a Asus Laptop (UX501J) running Windows 10.
When my system runs CPU intensive jobs such as compiling code, my mouse gets unresponsive rather often.

During these CPU-heavy tasks, my mouse gets somewhat unresponsive: The mouse pointer stops moving for a split second, even though I'm moving the mouse. 
When I move the mouse pointer with my computer's touchpad, it seems to be smooth without any "dropped movement info".

How can I find out what causes this? I would like to find out if it is the mouse, the driver, or my usb port, or the OS? Not sure where to start...

Comment: There really isn't much detail to go on here, but I think you answered your own question. Depending on your settings and configuration, when the CPU is heavily tasked other functions are delayed until the processor can get to them. This causes what appears to be freezing and jerking mouse movements. Unless there are more details you can share, we are left to only giving our opinions.

Comment: I was under the impression that modern multi-threading OS's would be able to allocate enough resources ( CPU cores? ) to the UI so that stuff like this wouldn't happen any more.

Comment: You have asked a very vague question, so there is no definite answer for you. Keep in mind, nothing is limitless. Again, it depends on your configuration and what you are doing. If you have maxed out the CPU with your compile process, then you can experience lag?

Comment: Value question: Yes :) -- Yes, the lag seems to happen when the machine is doing some heavy lifting.

Comment: Does this behavior exhibit itself while in a minimal boot configuration?